# Express the matrix expression $p(i,j)= (D I^\top) \cdot p$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider:

- a vector $D$ with dimension $n\times 1$ containing one element equal to one, and all the other elements equal to 0
- a vector $I$ with dimension $1\times n$ containing one element equal to one, and all the other elements equal to 0
- a matrix $p$ with dimension $n\times n$.

Suppose $D(i)=1$ and $I(j)=1$. I want to write down a formula which gives me $p(i,j)$.

This is my attempt:
$$
p(i,j)= (D I^\top) \cdot p
$$
where "$\cdot$ " denotes the element-wise product. Is there a simpler and more common notation to represent $p(i,j)$?

Comment: The convention is to use $e_k$ for both vectors:
$(I,D)\to (e_j,\;e_i).\;$
Standard notation usually reserves  $I$ for the **Identity** matrix (note that $e_k$ is its $k^{th}$ column). Finally, the components of any matrix can be extracted via pre/post multiplication:
$\;M_{ij} = e_i^TMe_j\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common way to do this is to write
$$p(i,j) = D^TpI$$
One advantage is that since this is a product of an $[1 \times n][n \times n][n \times 1]$ it reduces to a $[1 \times 1]$ matrix, or essentially just a scalar.

In general, if $x$ is $m \times 1, \ y$ is $n \times 1,$ and $A$ is $m \times n$ then

\begin{align}
    x^TAy &= x^T\begin{bmatrix} 
       \sum_{\ell=1}^n A(1,\ell)y(\ell) \\
       \vdots \\
       \sum_{\ell=1}^n A(m,\ell)y(\ell)
    \end{bmatrix} = \sum_{k=1}^m x(k) \sum_{\ell=1}^n A(k,\ell)y(\ell)\\
    &=\sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{\ell=1}^n x(k)A(k,\ell)y(\ell)
\end{align}

Specializing to your case, set $x = D, y = I, A = p$ to obtain
$$D^TpI = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^n D(k)p(k,\ell)I(\ell) = p(i,j)$$
where in the last equality we have used that $D(k)I(\ell) = 1$ when $k = i$ and $\ell = j$ and is 0 otherwise.